# Scrape website for certain text and send e-mail

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am fairly new to coding but I have a use case that I want to realize with python.

Use Case:
I'd like to have a python script that checks a certain website for a certain string. If the string is found I'd like to get some kind of notification or e-mail. Maybe you could point me to the right library or code snippets on how I can realize this.

Comment: Beautiful soup or Selenium for web scraping

Answer (score 0):

The Usecase that you mentioned (*Apart from sending notification/E-mail*) is called **Web Scraping**. I have mentioned different python modules below that will help you learn web-scraping.

- `Beautiful Soup` - Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.

> Docs: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

- `requests` - Requests is an elegant and simple HTTP library for Python.

> Docs: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

- `Selenium` - Selenium is an umbrella project for a range of tools and libraries that enable and support the automation of web browsers.

> Docs: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/